# Subscribing to a collection error

Tags: meteor

I'm really not sure what the issue is here. Maybe I don't understand the publish/subscribe docs enough.

In my server directory:

```
Meteor.publish("kudos", function () {
  return Kudos.find({});
});
```

In my client directory:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe("kudos");
});

Template.launchsection.kudos = function () {
  return Kudos.find({});
};
```

When I run this, I get an error of `Kudos is not defined` for the line that returns `Kudos.find({});`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you define the Schema in a js file which is executed on both, client and server. A file `Schema.js` in the root folder of your meteor app should do the trick. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483142/meteor-using-a-local-connection-results-in-error-insert-failed-404-method-n).

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Yup, that was it. I didn't know you needed to declare collections on both client and server. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Specifically, you need to write `Kudos = new Meteor.Collection("kudos")` in both your client and server directory.