# Meteor - insert failed: Method not found

Tags: meteor

I have a problem with my Meteor's JS file. I get this error "insert failed: Method not found" when I try to insert any data to the database and reflect on chart. I've tried fetching data directly from db that didn't work too...
thanx in advance.

```js
LinePeople = new Mongo.Collection("LinePeople");
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    console.log("in LIne Client");

    //LinePeople = new Mongo.Collection(null);

    Template.linenvd3.rendered = function() {
        var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .margin({left: 80})  //Adjust chart margins to give the x-axis some breathing room.
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)  //We want nice looking tooltips and a guideline!
            .transitionDuration(350)  //how fast do you want the lines to transition?
            .showLegend(true)       //Show the legend, allowing users to turn on/off line series.
            .showYAxis(true)        //Show the y-axis
            .showXAxis(true)        //Show the x-axis
        ;

        nv.addGraph(function() {
            chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Person number').tickFormat(d3.format('d'));
            chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Age (years)').tickFormat(d3.format('d'));
            d3.select('#lineChart svg').datum(
                [{ values: LinePeople.find().fetch(), key: 'Age' }]
            ).call(chart);
            nv.utils.windowResize(function() { chart.update() });
            return chart;
        });

        Deps.autorun(function () {
            d3.select('#lineChart svg').datum(
                [{ values: LinePeople.find().fetch(), key: 'Age' }]
            ).call(chart);
            chart.update();
        });
    };

    Template.linenvd3.events({
        'click #addDataButton': function() {

            console.log(" in line addButton");

            var age = getRandomInt(13, 89);
            var lastPerson = LinePeople.findOne({}, {fields:{x:1},sort:{x:-1},limit:1,reactive:false});
            if (lastPerson) {
                console.log(" in lastPerson.. if block");
                LinePeople.insert({x:(lastPerson.x + 1), y:age});
            } else {
                console.log(" in lastPerson.. else block");
                LinePeople.insert({x:1, y:age});
            }
        },
        'click #removeDataButton': function() {
            console.log(" in line removeButton");
            var lastPerson = LinePeople.findOne({}, {fields:{x:1},sort:{x:-1},limit:1,reactive:false});
            if (lastPerson) {
                LinePeople.remove(lastPerson._id);
            }
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    console.log("in line Server");

}
```

Comment: do you have `autopublish` active in your project? (`meteor list`)

Comment: also, can point to the offending line in the code where the error occurs? Are you sure it is even coming from meteor and not d3 or nv?

Comment: Yes, autopubish is active along with nvd3js and d3. It doesn't point to any line in the code but I can see that error in the console through "inspect element". I'm not sure if it is a problem with meteor / d3 / nv coz I'm new to meteor.  I even tried manually inserting data by LinePeople.insert({"x":1,"y":39"})... of course, the result was same.

Comment: Could you please reduce your question to the essentials then? If you simply cannot execute `LinePeople.insert({"x":1,"y":39"})` without getting an error and the insert not happening in the database, then please remove all the other unnecessary code to make it easy for people to try and replicate your error.

Comment: You should actually add the last comment as an answer to your own post

Comment: Once you remove the extraneous code, this is a duplicate of [Getting a error inserting in to a Meteor Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739810/getting-a-error-inserting-in-to-a-meteor-collection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the help... I actually got it worked by publishing the collection and giving it some permissions:

This code is placed in "myapp/shared/collections.js". (Placed them separately to handle all the other collections which I would add for other graphs)

```
lineVar = new Meteor.Collection("linenvd3");
lineVar.allow({
         insert: function () {
         return true;
         },
         update: function () {
         return true;
         },
         remove: function () {
         return true;
         }
         });
```

This code is placed in "myapp/server/publish.js"

```
Meteor.publish('line', function () {
           return lineVar.find();
           });
```

Then, this is modified Javascript made look more simpler and comprehensive.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Meteor.subscribe('line');
Template.linenvd3.rendered = function() {

    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
      .margin({left: 80})
      .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
      .transitionDuration(350)
      .showLegend(true)
      .showYAxis(true)        //Show the y-axis
      .showXAxis(true)        //Show the x-axis
    ;

    nv.addGraph(function() {
          chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Person number').tickFormat(d3.format('d'));
          chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Age (years)').tickFormat(d3.format('d'));
          d3.select('#lineChart svg').datum(
            [{ values: lineVar.find().fetch(), key: 'Age' }]
          ).call(chart);
          nv.utils.windowResize(function() { chart.update() });
          return chart;
    });

    Deps.autorun(function () {
          d3.select('#lineChart svg').datum(
            [{ values: lineVar.find().fetch(), key: 'Age' }]).call(chart);
          chart.update();
    });
};
}
```

Comment: This whole thing has nothing to do with d3. The problem was that you [didn't create the collection on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739810/getting-a-error-inserting-in-to-a-meteor-collection).

Answer (score 5):

While following the *Getting Started* tutorial on the official meteor.js website I've had the same problem with autopublish turned on.

Turned out the issue was I created my *Tasks* collection inside the `imports/` folder. Thus it was not implicitly imported on the server.

I had to explicitly import it on the server to solve the issue.

**`server/main.js`**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import '../imports/api/tasks.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {  
  // code to run on server at startup
});
```

As you can see the import is not used by my code but is required anyways.

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer. You solved my precious coding hours.

Comment: after hours of agony and despair... your answer saved a life from complete darkness :)

Comment: Found this while doing the getting started tutorial. At first everything was working, but after making some changes, it stopped working. Doing as this answer suggested fixed the problem, but I don't understand why it *did* work at first without explicitly giving access to the collection on the server.