# Meteor.publish callback not being called

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a very simple project with a single Meteor.publish call:

```
Boxes = new Meteor.Collection("boxes");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Boxes.remove({}) //clearing the database
    Boxes.insert({ //adding one element to the database
      boxes: [1],
      currentId: 1
    });
  });
  console.log("publish1")
  Meteor.publish("boxes", function() {
    console.log("publish2") //this does not run! ever!
    return Boxes.find();
  });
}
```

For some reason my Meteor.subscribe does not seem to be working (the collections always return empty), so I placed a couple of console.log in my code. For some reason my server code prints "publish1" but it does not print "publish2", while if I try the same in an example project it does print both.

note: I removed the autopublish package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe it on client. This work for me:

```
Boxes = new Meteor.Collection("boxes");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
 Meteor.startup(function () {
  Boxes.remove({}) //clearing the database
  Boxes.insert({ //adding one element to the database
    boxes: [1],
    currentId: 1
  });
});
console.log("publish1")
Meteor.publish("boxes", function() {
    console.log("publish2") //this does not run! ever!
    return Boxes.find();
  });
}

if(Meteor.isClient){

  Meteor.subscribe('boxes');

}
```

The `publish2` only get printed when you open app in browser.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense for the publish callback to only be called when a user  actually requests data. My problem was unrelated to this

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate JavaScript file in the path(`your_project/server/`) as `publish.js` and place the publish function in that file.

```
Meteor.publish("boxes", function() {
  console.log("publish2") //this does not run! ever!
  return Boxes.find();
});
```

Then subscribe this publishing in your corresponding JS file on client side as

```
Meteor.subscribe('boxes');
```

Comment: If it still raises an exception for permission or access to "boxes" then you will have to add the following code in `your_project/shared/collections.js`.

    `Boxes = new Meteor.Collection("boxes");
    Boxes.allow({
         insert: function () {
         return true;
         },
         update: function () {
         return true;
         },
         remove: function () {
         return true;
         }
         });`

If required, check out my previous [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223725/meteor-insert-failed-method-not-found/28667898#28667898) similar to this.