# meteor - inserting data to database gives error "insert failed: Method '/texts/insert' not found"

Tags: meteor

I have this other project that broke somehow(i have no idea) and I rebuilt the app with the same file names and code and is now working fine.  My only problem is that when I go to insert data into the database called `texts` i get an error like this `insert failed: Method '/texts/insert' not found` I do not know what is wrong because I copied every line of code from my previous project and this problem came up that wasn't there before.  What confuses me is that when I create user accounts with the `Accounts.createuser()` it works fine.

**SendText.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {Texts} from "./../api/Text";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
import {Accounts} from "meteor/accounts-base"

class SendText extends React.Component{
    send(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let message = this.refs.message.value;
        let name = Accounts.user().username
        if(name != ""){
            if(message){
                Texts.insert({
                    name,
                    message
                });
                this.refs.message.value = ""
            }
        }
        console.log(Texts)
    }
    logoutUser(){
        Accounts.logout();
        this.props.history.push("/login")
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form className="position-fixed sendInputs" onSubmit={this.send.bind(this)}>
                    <input className="inputMessage" placeholder="Say Something" type="text" ref="message"/>
                    <button className="chatButtons">Send</button>
                    <button className="chatButtons" onClick={this.logoutUser.bind(this)}>Logout</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(SendText);
```

**Text.js**

```
import {Mongo} from "meteor/mongo";

export const Texts = new Mongo.Collection("texts");
```

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223725/meteor-insert-failed-method-not-found

Comment: More specifically, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739810/getting-a-error-inserting-in-to-a-meteor-collection