# Meteor: insert failed: Method not found

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I am receiving the `insert failed: Method not found` log message and it probably is the result of what is described in these threads:

- [Meteor using a local connection results in error: insert failed: 404 -- Method not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483142/meteor-using-a-local-connection-results-in-error-insert-failed-404-method-n)
- [Getting a error inserting in to a Meteor Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739810/getting-a-error-inserting-in-to-a-meteor-collection)

However, I'm not seeing how. Let me show the code in hopes that will explain more clearly. I'm using Coffeescript:

```
if Meteor.isClient
  @VINs = new Meteor.Collection("vins")

  scoped_vins = @VINs
  Template.vins.events =
    "click .icon-plus-sign": ->
      console.log "this is #{this}"
      realVIN = $("#your-vin").val().replace /\D/g, ''
      console.log "user id is: #{Meteor.userId()} vin is #{parseInt(realVIN)}"
      VINs.insert number: parseInt(realVIN), owner: Meteor.userId() if Meteor.userId()
      $("#your-vin").val('')
else
  @VINs = new Meteor.Collection("vins")
```

I'm totally a n00b with Meteor, but what I've gleaned from the above-cited threads is that the *collection* must be available on the client and the server. Is that not what I have done, or am I developing Coffee-blindness?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [Meteor using a local connection results in error: insert failed: 404 -- Method not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483142/meteor-using-a-local-connection-results-in-error-insert-failed-404-method-n)

Comment: A good first step as a n00b is to remove any code that's not relevant to reproducing the error. E.g. the `replace` on the VIN probably has nothing to do with the error, so trying removing it. Does the error still occur? Keep removing code until you isolate the minimum reproduction case.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make sure you've also declared your collection on the server as well as the client.

In your code above `@VINs = new Meteor.Collection("vins")` in both the client and server so what it might be is that you've put your code into the `/client` directory?

If so this means that the code will only be run on the client, even though you have the `else` for the `if Meteor.isClient` block.

To rectify this, copy the line you used into a `.coffee` file in the `/server` directory:

```
@VINs = new Meteor.Collection("vins")
```

Comment: And... you nailed it on the first try :) It was a combination of my lack of understanding and some directory reorganization.

Comment: I wasnt too sure! If it solved your problem you also don't need the `if Meteor.isClient..else..` because it will already run on the client and server depending on the directories the files are in. If you put your files in the root directory then you could use the `if Meteor.isClient` (like the todos example)

Comment: Right. Well, thanks! I'm getting there. Just not as quickly as I'd guessed. Only my second mongo project and I have to keep my head out of the relational space.

Comment: Cool stuff, if you get stuck on anything else ask away. Will be sure to at least try and answer