# Inserting Data into Meteor Collections

Tags: javascript, collections, insert, meteor

I followed this tutorial exactly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVr02nLZ6u4
The only difference is that I tried to insert the data into a 'users' collection which already exists as confirmed by Robomongo because I have the accounts-ui and accounts-password packages installed. When I got to the end and tried to insert data into the collection, I received the following error as detailed in this first screen shot. In the second screenshot you can see that the collection exists. In the final screenshot, you can see my source code. In closing, I also tried the collection I created in the source code and it responded with "Uncaught ReferenceError: consumer is not defined" in the console. I'd prefer to insert into the users table but am OK with inserting to the consumer table I made up. Having said that, I'd appreciate solutions for both instances. Thank you!

[image: This is the error after I followed the directions exactly]

[image: Here you can see that the 'users' collection exists]

[image: My JS source code]

[image: My HTML source code]

Thanks for the help once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access `users` collection then use **[Meteor.users](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users)**.

Another thing is that creation of `user` document should be done with [Accounts.createUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser) which comes from [accounts-password](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_passwords) package.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm a complete self taught beginner and I don't see how your responses help me write code that will enable data from a form to be inserted to the database. Could you elaborate? Btw, Kuba - very cool site (http://kubawyrobek.com/)!

Comment: After further investigation, I happened upon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518449/meteor-insert-failed-method-not-found 
Which clearly shows that the collection must be declared on the server and client.

Comment: That's correct, but I thought you were going to use Meteor builtin users collection with `accounts-password` package. I'm glad you like my site.

Comment: `Meteor.users` is not a function (:

Comment: @PeppeL-G you are absolutely  right, my mistake... Please don't hesitate to edit my answer if you see such heresy ;-)