# Insert failed in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

```
insert failed: Method '/players/insert' not found
```

Getting the above error while calling the insert function in meteor mongodb using chrome console:-

```
PlayersList.insert({ name: "David", score: 0 });
```

Any help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor: insert failed: Method not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518449/meteor-insert-failed-method-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because you defined your collection in the client side.
Try to put it in "lib" directory.